# Changing axis endpoints in iTorch plot

Tags: plot, torch

I'm trying to graph some data in an iTorch notebook. I can generate plots fine, but I want to change the endpoints of the axes. (My autogenerated y-axis is from 20-100, but I'd rather it be from 0-100 since it's a graph of percentages and I want the lower left corner to be the origin.)

I looked in the documentation, and in the list of methods implemented, and in the source code, but didn't find anything that lets me do this. I can zoom the generated graph, but it preserves aspect ratio, so I can't zoom just one of the axes.

Does anyone know how to do this? I'm half convinced this isn't implemented, but it seems like a very strange feature to leave out.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the axis scale by mouse-scrolling over the axis ticks, and translate by drag-and-drop.

I know it's not ideal, but I had the same problem and that's the best I could find so far.